Handle windows-style paths in CLI
On a windows machine local paths are prepended with a .\ (for example autocompletion does that). However, if I run pdflatex (or other flavors, that is not that important) on such path as-is, I get
PS> pdflatex.exe .\file.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> .\file
            .tex
?

Yet if I manually delete the leading .\, the compilation starts.
I wonder if there is a setting and/or configuration key that would allow running pdflatex .\file.tex without additional manipulations.
(Please feel free to add/change question tags, I put only the most generic ones).

it is built in at a very core level that a \  on the commandline is interpreted as a command not a filename, so within tex itself  that is hard to change however you can of course have a bat file or powershell script or whatever that accepts commandline arguments changes any \  to / then calls pdflatex with the modified arguments

@DavidCarlisle that's a bummer. I have a large-ish build system, fixing path handling in all appropriate places is not trivial.

tex wants you to be able to do pdflatex \def\foo{wibble} \input{filename} so having .\file mean ./file is tricky.
